# use rsjx and vue-rx in vue-cli

Tags: rxjs, vuejs2, vue-cli

when I use rxjs and vue-rx in my vue-cli program,I refer to vue-rx docs and configure my program，but found ‘Rx is not defined‘,wish somebody can help me,thans a lot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOY2f.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0UVs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions

1.import Rx before use.
`import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'`

2.define a global variable in `./build/webpack.base.conf.js`,cause you use vue-cli.

`plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      "window.Rx":"rxjs/Rx",
      "Rx":"rxjs/Rx"
    })
  ]`